# Bootstrap columns break even inside rows and containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

So I'm building a webpage using Bootstrap 3 and some LESS mixins.

Whenever I try to make a two column layout, say using `.make-sm-column(4);` and `.make-sm-column(8);` the right column always overflows to the next row.

I understand that to account for the `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `15px` you need to have your columns within a row and that row be inside of a container. On a basic level, the LESS I am using looks like:

```
.container {
  .container();
  //...

  .content {
    .make-row();

    .col1 {
      .make-md-column(8);
    }

    .col2 {
      .make-md-column(4);
    }
  }
}
```

Still, for some reason, the columns seem to be too wide for the container and break over. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing that I can't see? My only fix for now is to remove the `padding-left/right` but that is hacky and of course removing this gutter doesn't make the two columns look clean next to each other without me needing to do any extra work.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see which CSS rules are applied? For bootstrap, there is `{ float: left; }` for `col-md-*` - is there one for `.col1, .col2`?

Comment: @Kenney, yes, `.col1` has the styling: `float: left; width: 66.66666667%; position: relative;  min-height: 1px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;` whereas `.col2` has the same except for `width` is `33.33333333%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the padding it gets fixed?

It must be a problem with the box-sizing. The padding makes the columns bigger than the width specified. Change the property to:
`box-sizing: border-box;` and that should do it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.